# Why does Harara have boobs?

Tags: apocalypse-zero

Why does Harara Hagakure have boobs?  We see them from the beginning of the OVA (meaning, there is never a time that he doesn't have boobs), and the boots of his armor have heels like a set of female armor would.  He's constantly referred to as Kakugo Hagakure's older brother.

Back in those days, strange production things happened, so was it a sudden change in story after the animation had been completed?  Or is this a translation issue? Like [Sanji's lolipop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoSmoking), for example.

Answer (score 1):

[As explained by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_Zero#Characters), bonding Fortified Armor Shell Kasumi, caused him to take on hermaphroditic characteristics, which could explain the boobs and the heel-like appendages.

> Kakugo's older brother and the main antagonist of the series. Harara possesses the Fortified Armor Shell Kasumi (霞(かすみ)). Bonding with Kasumi caused his body to assume a hermaphroditic form and drove him to insanity, killing his father Oboro in combat and defeating Kakugo.